# Adding a claim to IdentityRole in IdentityServer 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I use to have this before upgrading my application to .NET Core 2.0 and IdentityServer 4.

```
var role = new IdentityRole("Admin");
role.Claims.Add(new IdentityRoleClaim<string> { ClaimType = "IsAdmin", ClaimValue = "True" });
```

This no longer works, I tried Google, but couldn't see anything clear. The exact error is:

[image: error]

How can I add a claim to IdentityRole with IdentityServer 4?

Comment: what exactly error you're getting?

Comment: added a screenshot showing the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by ,

Install **`Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.AspNetCoreCompat`** from **`NuGet`**. And then   add reference of **`Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.AspNetCoreCompat.`**

After that, you will get the exception as image below.

[image]

Install **`Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework,`** and fix all compiler errors.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the `role` first with `CreateAsync` and then use `AddClaimAsync`

```
  var role = new IdentityRole("Admin");
  await _roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
  await _roleManager.AddClaimAsync(role, new Claim(type: "IsAdmin", value: "True"));
```

Answer (score -1):

You have no direct access to the Claims collection directly now.
You have to use the RoleManager's related functions instead.
Inject your RoleManager then use it as follows:

```
var role = new IdentityRole("Admin");
var claim = new Claim(type: "IsAdmin", value: "True");
await roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
await roleManager.AddClaimAsync(role, claim);
```

Updated based on @Joe's input

Comment: You need to await the `roleManager ...` and create the role before adding the claim.  Add `await _roleMgr.CreateAsync(role);` between your two statements.  Update your answer and I'll upvote.

Comment: That is not what I said and it doesn't work.  Did you even test it in the OP setup before posting?

Comment: @Joe, updated again, it may be my fault, but i never told i am posting a full solution, it is a snippet.

Comment: @Joe , thank you for the support by down voting and copying the answer :)